# If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, is $\mu((0, x]) < \infty$ for all $x > 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Say I have some $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $\mu((0, x]) < \infty$ for all $ x > 0$?

The motivation for my question comes from a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDPZPOsGNbk&list=PLo4jXE-LdDTQq8ZyA8F8reSQHej3F6RFX&index=31) on decomposition of distribution, where the following set of measures is defined:
$$
\mathcal{M} = \{\mu : \mu  \text{ is $\sigma$-finite, } \mu((-\infty, 0]) < \infty\}
$$
The lecturer then claims that $\mu((-\infty, x]) < \infty$ for all $x$. This is clear when $x < 0$ since then
$$
\mu((-\infty, x]) \leq \mu((-\infty, 0]) < \infty
$$
For $x > 0$ the lecturer, uses subadditivity to conclude
$$
\mu((-\infty, x]) \leq \mu((-\infty, 0]) + \mu((0, x])
$$
The first term is less than $\infty$ by assumption. The lecturer claims that $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ implies $\mu((0, x]) < \infty$. How would I go about proving this?

This is important as the lecturer then goes on to define the cumulative function $F_{\mu}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

$$
F_{\mu}(x) = \mu((-\infty, x])
$$

If $\mu((-\infty, x]) = \infty$, then this function is not well-defined.

Comment: If the measure $\mu$ is regular on $\mathbb{R}$, the answer is yes. Otherwise, the example provided in the answer shows that masters of bounded sets may not be finite. The "measure" $\mu(dx)=\frac{1}{|x|}\,dx$ is not regular (a Radon measure) on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. It is regular on $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ though.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks, could you provide some explanation as to why regularity helps here?

Comment: If the measure $\mu$ is regular on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\mu(K)<\infty$ for all compact sets $K\subset \mathbb{R}$. In particular $\mu((0,x])\leq \mu([0,x])<\infty$. Another thing, regular measures on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ are automatically $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: So what we really need is for $\mu$ to be a Radon measure correct? If the measure $\mu$ is only regular then there is no guarantee that the infimum (wrt outer regularity) or supremum (wrt to inner regularity) are finite? Whereas if the measure is a Radon measure then as you said $[0, x]$ has finite measure and we are done.

Comment: When I say regular, I mean inner and outer regular (or Radon) I reserve Radon also for other things. Bounded sets are included in compact sets and thus, the measure of a bounded set is finite when the measure is (inner) regular.

Comment: So to be clear, your definition of inner regularity is as follows? For every set $A \in \mathcal{B}$ we have $\mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K) : \text{ compact } K \subseteq A\}$. Does regularity guarantee that this supremum is finite, or are you implicitly assuming that when you say $\mu$ is regular?

Comment: Not only that, but also $\mu(K)<\infty$ for all compacts. You can call it Radon if you will. I tend to reserve the latter term for linear functionals on $\mathcal{C}_{00}(X)$, $X$ loc. compact HAsutdorff.

Comment: Ah okay, I see now thank you! I am new to these definitions, so it takes a bit of getting use to for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not missing anything, this should be a counterexample: let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure and define $\mu = f \lambda$ where :
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R, f(x)  =\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \text{if } x \leq 0 \\
\frac{1}{x} & \text{if } x >0\end{array}\right.$$
Then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite (and $\mu((-\infty,0]) <\infty$), but $\mu((0,x]) = \infty$ for  any $x>0$

Comment: I don't think it's $\sigma -$finite...

Comment: Well $\mu((-\infty,0]\cup (1/n,n))< \infty$ and the union of such sets over all positive integers $n$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Does the notation here mean $\mu(A) = \int_{A}f(x) d\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, that is how $\mu$ is defined

Comment: @SolubleFish: your measure $\mu$ is indeed $\sigma$-finite on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, but it is not regular. In any event, the OP did not specified.

Comment: @SolubleFish: If the measure $\mu$ is regular (call it Radon if you will), then (a) the measure of any bounded set is finite (2) the measure is automatically $\sigma$-finite.